# Displaying the first service description below average price

Tags: java

I want to display the first service desciption(getSdescrip) below the average price(getPrice).
This is as far as i can go with my coding.Any help?

```
public static void BelowAverage(Service [] serviceObject)
{
   double sum =0.0; double avg = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
   {
     sum+= serviceObject[i].getPrice();  
   }
     avg = sum/6;         
}
```

Comment: define belowAverage? How much?

Comment: What is `getSDescrip`?

Comment: Are you certain that serviceObject[] will always have 6 elements? It will crash if that's not the case

Answer (score 0):

Your headed in the right direction. Now i would just loop through the array again and compare each price to your average price. As soon you get to a price that is below the avg, then just return that service object description.

Comment: Comparing the price with the average is my problem.Sample code would be helpful

Comment: @LanceDaKotaSA You use the "less than" operator